# Posting to news feed with specified username and password

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

How do you post an update to a Facebook wall with Facebook PHP SDK and not need an authentication every time we call the script, when we have just specified an username and a password?  I just read this link, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/, but we still need to log in.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the API without authentication. It defeats the purpose of privileged access to the API.

Please read up on authentication and extended access tokens.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: thank you, in case we want post an article to our web and the link to facebook wall at once, how to do that?